# Reshaping dataframe (columns and rows)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape

I have the following random (shortened) dataset with dates and quintile:

| Date | Quintile |
| --- | --- |
| 05/03/2021 | 5 |
| 05/03/2021 | 3 |
| 05/03/2021 | 1 |
| 04/03/2021 | 2 |
| 04/03/2021 | 4 |
| 03/03/2021 | 4 |
| 03/03/2021 | 1 |
| 03/03/2021 | 2 |

I would like to reshape the dataframe as follows:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/03/2021 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 04/03/2021 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 03/03/2021 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The new data frame will be aggregated by date, with the individual quintiles the new columns. I've explored the dplyr functions but I can't quite get it right :(

I set the Quintile values 'as.character' but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: How about `aggregate(Quintile ~ Date, myDF, table)`

Comment: Cheers, I've tried it and it doesn't work unfortunately. It produces a list of the counts of how many times the quintile appears in each date segment within the quintile column. This is a pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pivot_wider` with some modifications

**Edit:** Add unique identifier row for each Date and then use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyverse)

# your data
df <- tribble(
  ~Date,    ~Quintile, 
  "05/03/2021", 5,
  "05/03/2021", 3, 
  "05/03/2021", 1, 
  "04/03/2021", 2, 
  "04/03/2021", 4, 
  "03/03/2021", 4, 
  "03/03/2021", 1, 
  "03/03/2021", 2)

df1 <- df %>% 
  arrange(Quintile) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Quintile) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% # unique identifier
  mutate(count = n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Quintile, values_from = count) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  select(-row) # remove unique identifier
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this code worked in terms of formatting the table as displayed above, however the values were not correct. The warning message was 'Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols'. I assume this is because there are duplicates in the data. Any idea how I prevent this without removing the duplicates, because this will be presented as a time series? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it with my edit. I created a unique identifier `mutate(row = row_number())`.

Comment: Ah my bad. So your initial code worked perfectly, and produced the result I needed with my example above (can't fault you there, it worked great!). When I tried it on my actual dataset, which has the same number of columns but 20 observations, the warning message appeared. I'll post the actual dataframe on the end of this thread, if you could have a look it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Ben_Kimpton have you update the question with the updated data with the error?

Comment: @SinhNguyen I've added the results to the answer elsewhere in the thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the dataset which I am actually working with, and the dataset in which the error actually occurs (as mentioned in a comment on the TarJae's answer).

[image]

Edit:

Here's the dataframe when I run TarJae's code (excluding the unique Identifiers) on the dataframe above. No warning errors are produced, there just seems to be issues with the values.

[image]

With the Unique Identifiers, the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple base R option using `table`

```
> table(df)
            Quintile
Date         1 2 3 4 5
  03/03/2021 1 1 0 1 0
  04/03/2021 0 1 0 1 0
  05/03/2021 1 0 1 0 1
```

---

or `reshape`

```
reshape(
  data.frame(table(df)),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Date",
  timevar = "Quintile")
```

gives

```
        Date Freq.1 Freq.2 Freq.3 Freq.4 Freq.5
1 03/03/2021      1      1      0      1      0
2 04/03/2021      0      1      0      1      0
3 05/03/2021      1      0      1      0      1
```

---

or `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  Quintile ~ Date, 
  df, 
  function(x) table(factor(x, levels = sort(unique(df$Quintile)))))
```

gives

```
        Date Quintile.1 Quintile.2 Quintile.3 Quintile.4 Quintile.5
1 03/03/2021          1          1          0          1          0
2 04/03/2021          0          1          0          1          0
3 05/03/2021          1          0          1          0          1
```